# Event Listenter e Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Galera, este é o meu primeiro post. Desculpa se não segui alguma regra/etiqueta de publicação.

Fiz um formulario em html que manda dados para um arquivo em php.
Depois coloquei ajax pra não dar reload na pag. Até aí ok.
Mas o html e ajax estão no mesmo scrip e quero separar eles.

O formulario tem um botao de responder. Então pensei em fazer no arquivo js. um querySelector com o id do formulario e addEventListener, e, quando o click ocorresse, ele executaria o ajax. É possível fazer isso?

1 - Ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   

    $("#form_resp_<?=$row['id']?>").submit(function(e){
    //event.preventDefaut();

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url : 'banco-responder.php',
        data: {
        id : $("#id-resposta-<?=$row['id']?>").val() ,
        resposta : $("#resposta-pergunta-<?=$row['id']?>").val()
    }
        }).done(function(data){
        console.log($("#card-<?=$row['id']?>").hide());
        alert("Respondido com Sucesso!");
        }).fail(function(){
        alert('Deu pau');
        });
    return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

2 - Query Selector/addEventListener:

```
<script>                            
    var botaoResponder = document.querySelector("#botao_resp_<?=$row['id']?>");
    botaoResponder.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("teste: Botão responder foi clicado com sucesso!!!");

    });
</script>
```

Quero colocar o ajax dentro do addEventListener quando o click acontecer e depois assim separar os arquivos. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o jQuery para fazer isso, usando o método [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), por exemplo:

```js
/** Seu arquivo JavaScript separado. */

(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  
  $(function () {
    $('#ajax-button').on('click', function () {
      alert('Você clicou no botão!');
      
      /** Do stuff. */
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!-- Seu arquivo HTML -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <button id="ajax-button">Clique-me!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Não consegui fazer :(
Coloquei em outro arquivo .js isso aqui:
<script> 
    $("#botao_resp_<?=$row['id']?>").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Você clicou no botão!');
 $.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url : 'banco-responder.php',
  data: {
  id : $("#id-resposta-<?=$row['id']?>").val() ,
  resposta : $("#resposta-pergunta-<?=$row['id']?>").val()
 }
  }).done(function(data){
  console.log($("#card-<?=$row['id']?>").hide());
  alert("Respondido com Sucesso!");
  }).fail(function(){
  alert('Deu pau');
  });
 return false;
    });
</script>

Comment: Importei no html:
<script src="principal.js" ></script>

E no console do aparece isso:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #botao_resp_<?=$row['id']?>

Comment: No arquivo do javascript você não deve incluir as tags `<script>` e `</script>`.

Comment: Tirei as tags e nada ainda.